# Rails, rspec, post array like "hey[]=1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rspec

I need to test if client includes POINTS array in post-request. When I test it with RESTClient plugin for firefox, I do it like this:

```
POINTS[]=1.111111,2.222222,77
```

and it works. Now I need to test it via rspec, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here is my rspec test request:

```
post :event, DISTANCE: "12345", POINTS: { "1" => "1.111111,2.222222,77" }
```

But somehow it does not work. **puts p.inspect** shows: ["1", "1.111111,2.222222,77"] and it's not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: POINTS: ["1.111111,2.222222,77" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in comments, do:

```
post :event, distance: "12345", points:  ["1.111111,2.222222,77"]
```